# KeyboardEvent only works after MouseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, flash-cs5, keyboard-events

Ok, so I am creating a slideshow presentation in Flash CS5. The code is very basic, however it does not work as intended. It's supposed to go to the next frame if i press a button, or press up/right arrow on the keyboard. However, the keyboard only works after I've pressed a button once.

my code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

slides.stop();

addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyD);
FB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextSld);
BB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, prevSld);

function keyD(evt){
    var k = evt.keyCode;
    if(k==37||k==38){ 
        prevSld(evt);
    }
    if(k==39||k==40){ 
        nextSld(evt);
    }
}
function nextSld(evt){
    slides.nextFrame();
    }
function prevSld(evt){
    slides.prevFrame(); 
}
```

slides is a movieclip, where I've stored all my slides (Oh, by the way, I know my setup isn't the best, but I wouldn't use a lot of time on it, as it's for a religion class). FB is forward button, and you can guess what BB is...

Now, I would just make sure my problem isn't here, and maybe someone can point out the problem, even though this probably don't fit on this board.

Comment: is this problem present in standalone flashplayer?

Comment: Are you sure the flash movie has focus? It can't respond to keyboard events unless it has focus, usually this means clicking the flash movie in the browser. Try clicking in a blank area of the SWF, then using the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyD);` to `stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyD);`

Comment: Well, this is kind of embarrassing. I thought I had done this, but it worked now. Thanks.

Comment: btw there's a `flash.ui.Keyboard` class with keycode constants, very helpful: `function keyD(evt:KeyboardEvent):void{ if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN || evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)//and so on`

Answer (score 1):

Seems your movie is not in focus, so you need some mouse click on movie before it will grab keyboard events.

Comment: Well, I tried this, but the keyboard won't react unless I specifically press one of the buttons. If I just click on the movie, nothing happens.